# Simple specification of the global size of smartdiagrams

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

I am thinking of using smartdiagram package in beamer presentation.
I found various size options, but my interest is simplest so as to fit the size of the diagram within the beamer slide size without interfering with each respective components like text size or arrow length. I just want to magnify / shrink the diagram without touching the details.

What is your simplest way of accomplishing the above?

MWE:

```
\begin{frame}{Smart Diagram Package}

    \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Edit, \LaTeX, Bib\TeX/ biber, make\-index, \LaTeX}

\end{frame}
```

causes an overfull in beamer.

I apologize in advance if the solution is nothing specific to smartdiagram package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm normally not a big fan of scaling elements which contain text, but smartdiagram seems to be difficult to tame otherwise ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Smart Diagram Package}

  \begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{.8\textheight}}
    \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Edit, \LaTeX, Bib\TeX/ biber, make\-index, \LaTeX}
  \end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]